# Python: Multiple instances seem to be sharing properties (or something?!)

Tags: python, multiple-instances

Python is my first language, and I am very new to it, so the answer may be very clear, but after many hours looking and experimenting, I am not sure what is causing the problem.

An overview of the module:
The DicePool module is meant to manage collections of "dice", stored as dictionary items. Each dictionary key (herein poolKey) has a list containing information about one "type" of dice, most importantly, a tuple describing its faces and an integer representing the quantity of "dice" type 'x' in the "pool."

My specific question regards the Transfer method, which used to be two methods (send and receive, basically), but which I thought I could combine into one method. When the test code at the bottom runs, I'd like it to leave dp.dictPool[poolKey][1] == 0 and dp2.dictPool[poolKey][1] == 2. But in every attempt I've made, the values come out the same. Sorry I can't categorize this question better . . . I don't really know what the problem is.

Anyway, one half of the Transfer method is supposed to run for the "sender" instance, and one half is supposed to run for the "receiver" instance.

```
import random

class DicePool(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dictPool = {}

    def AddDice(self, poolKey, faces = 6, quant = 1, color = "white"):
        '''faces must be int or items 'a,b,c'; count must be int or def to 1'''
        try: #if count is not an integer, it defaults to 1
            quant = int(quant)
        except:
            print("Quant is not an integer, defaulting to 1")
            quant = 1
        try: #if faces is can be int, a list is built of numbers 1 to faces
            faces = int(faces)
            if faces < 2: #a 1 or 0-sided die breaks the program
                faces = 2
            tempList = []
            for i in range(1, faces+1):
                tempList.append(i)
            faces = tempList
        except: #if faces is not an integer, it is split into list items by ","
            faces = faces.split(",")
        if poolKey in self.dictPool.keys(): #if the key already exists in pool
            self.dictPool[poolKey][1] += quant #add to the quantity, 
        else: #if the key does not already exist, set all attributes
            self.dictPool[poolKey] = [faces, quant, color]

    def Transfer(self, poolKey, targetPool, sendQuant, senderPool = None):
        '''targetPool must be DicePool instance'''
        if targetPool:
            self.dictPool[poolKey][1] -= sendQuant
            targetPool.Transfer(poolKey, None, sendQuant, self)
        else:
            try:
                self.dictPool[poolKey][1] -= sendQuant
            except:
                self.dictPool[poolKey] = senderPool.dictPool[poolKey]
                self.dictPool[poolKey][1] = sendQuant

dp = DicePool()
dp2 = DicePool()

dp.AddDice("d6")
dp.AddDice("d6")
dp.Transfer("d6",dp2,2)
print(dp.dictPool,dp2.dictPool)
```

Comment: Why did you combine `send` and `receive`? You should separate your code by function.

Comment: Aside: don't use bare excepts.  Specify the exceptions explicitly.  Bare excepts make code very difficult to debug..

Comment: Note that dp2 won't have anything in it . . .

Comment: dp2 actually does have something in it, because the dp.Transfer function calls dp2.Transfer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
self.dictPool[poolKey] = senderPool.dictPool[poolKey]
```

The values in your dictPools are lists.  Here, you set one object's dictPool value to *the same list* as in the other one.  Not a copy of the list, but the same list.  So later if you add or subtract from that list, it will affect the other as well, because they are sharing one list object.

Try doing `self.dictPool[poolKey] = senderPool.dictPool[poolKey][:]`.  The `[:]` grabs the contents of the list rather than the list object iself.

Comment: shouldn't self.dictPool be dp2.dictPool and senderPool.dictPool be dp.dictPool? If they are the same list (unless I'm tired and misreading things), I must be misunderstanding something about scope or so.

Comment: @Anticipate, it's the lists that are contained in the dictPool that will be the same object, not the dictPools themselves. But in the sample code shown, will that line of code even get executed?

Comment: @Anticipate, never mind - I can see that dp2 has nothing in it, so when you try to do the subtraction it will hit the except clause. My bad.

Comment: P.S. This is one of the most maddening aspects of Python. Most other languages will actually make a copy when you use the `=` operator, and most of the time Python behaves as if it did a copy as well. That makes it surprising when it doesn't.

Comment: OK Mark, so you seem to be right: I wrote a little piece of test code that works similarly, and it works properly when the value to be changed is an integer, but it does NOT work if the value to be changed is an integer inside a list. So how can I make each instance access its own list?

Answer (score 0):

In both parts of the if/else in `Transfer` you're subtracting the quantity. Don't you want to subtract it in one case but add it in the other?

Comment: Yes, but it actually doesn't change the problem. See Steve Tjoa's response.

Comment: @Anticipate, so you had two bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Is `else: try: self.dictPool[poolKey][1] -= sendQuant` supposed to be `+= sendQuant` instead?

Might be a semantic issue, not a Python syntax issue.

Comment: Er, yes. That should be +=, but it still doesn't work (in fact, += and -= yield the same result...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of the Transfer() method that seems to work as intended (more or less), although it's very clumsy looking:

```
def Transfer(self, poolKey, targetPool, sendQuant, senderPool = None):
    '''targetPool must be DicePool instance'''
    if isinstance(targetPool, DicePool):
        #valid target, so subtract dice here, then call Transfer on target
        temp = self.dictPool[poolKey][1:2][0] - sendQuant
        print("sent",sendQuant,"leaving",temp)
        targetPool.Transfer(poolKey, "Receiver", sendQuant, self)
    elif targetPool == "Receiver":
        #this executes if a DicePool is named as the targetPool of Transfer
        if poolKey in self.dictPool.keys():
            self.dictPool[poolKey][1:2][0] += sendQuant
        else:
            self.dictPool[poolKey] = senderPool.dictPool[poolKey]
            self.dictPool[poolKey][1:2] = [sendQuant]
        print("now have",self.dictPool[poolKey][1:2][0])
        pass
    else:
        print("Not a valid targetPool, apparently")
```